# Laravel Chunk not reducing PHP memory size

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, eloquent, chunking

I'm hitting the Heroku PHP memory limits (512MB) when attempting to pull more than 25k records from my MySQL database using [Eloquent chunking](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#chunking-results). In a nutshell, I'm defining my SQL query, chunking it, and then feeding the results into a [PHPSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). According to the docs, chunking should reduce my memory usage, but in practice, it doesn't seem to be.

Am I doing anything obviously wrong in the code below? (I think most of the specifics of my query are totally irrelevant, so sorry for the extra scroll, but wanted to include it in case I'm doing something wrong in it.)

```
        $query = Participant::query()
        ->join('events', 'participants.event_id', '=', 'events.id')
        ->where('events.is_archived', '=', 'false')
        ->leftJoin('users as cu', 'participants.created_by_id', '=', 'cu.id')
        ->leftJoin('users as su', 'participants.selected_by_id', '=', 'su.id')
        ->select(\DB::raw(
            'events.title as event_title,' . // A
            'events.store_number as event_store_number,' . // B
            'events.workfront_id as event_workfront_id,' . // C
            'events.company as event_company,' . // D
            'events.business as event_business,' . // E
            'DATE_FORMAT(events.start_date, "%m/%d/%Y") as event_start_date,' . // F
            'DATE_FORMAT(events.end_date, "%m/%d/%Y") as event_end_date,' . // G
            'events.region as event_region,' . // H
            'events.state as event_state,' . // I
            'events.default_language as event_language,' . // J
            'events.description as event_description,' . // K
            'participants.first_name as participant_first_name,' . // L
            'participants.last_name as participant_last_name,' . // M
            'CASE WHEN participants.is_contact <> 0 THEN participants.email ELSE "NO CONTACT" END as participant_email,' . // N
            'CASE WHEN participants.is_contact <> 0 THEN participants.phone ELSE "NO CONTACT" END as participant_phone,' . // O
            'participants.zip_code as participant_zip_code,' . // P
            'participants.language as participant_language,' . // Q
            'CASE WHEN participants.is_customer <> 0 THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END as participant_is_customer,' . // R
            'participants.current_carrier as participant_current_carrier,' . // S
            'CASE WHEN participants.is_contact <> 0 THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END as participant_is_contact,' . // T
            'DATE_FORMAT(participants.created_at, "%m/%d/%Y") as participant_created_date,' . // U
            'cu.first_name as creating_user_first_name,' . // V
            'cu.last_name as creating_user_last_name,' . // W
            'cu.email as creating_user_email,' . // X
            'DATE_FORMAT(participants.selected_date, "%m/%d/%Y") as participant_selected_date,' . // Y
            'su.first_name as selecting_user_first_name,' . // Z
            'su.last_name as selecting_user_last_name,' . // AA
            'su.email as selecting_user_email,' . // AB
            'CASE WHEN events.has_surveys_enabled <> 0 THEN "yes" ELSE "no" END as has_surveys_enabled,' . // AC
            'CASE WHEN events.has_surveys_enabled <> 0 THEN "N/A" ELSE CONCAT("' . request()->getHost() . '/surveys/create?event_id=", events.id) END as survey_link' // AD
        ))
        ->orderBy('events.title')
        ->orderBy('participants.created_at')
    ;

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    $sheetRowIndex = 1;

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    $query->chunk(1000, function ($eventRecords) use (&$sheet, &$sheetRowIndex) {
        foreach ($eventRecords as $eventRecord) {
            $sheet->fromArray([
                $eventRecord->event_title,
                $eventRecord->event_store_number,
                $eventRecord->event_workfront_id,
                $eventRecord->event_company,
                $eventRecord->event_business,
                $eventRecord->event_start_date,
                $eventRecord->event_end_date,
                $eventRecord->event_region,
                $eventRecord->event_state,
                $eventRecord->event_language,
                $eventRecord->event_description,
                $eventRecord->participant_first_name,
                $eventRecord->participant_last_name,
                $eventRecord->participant_email,
                $eventRecord->participant_phone,
                $eventRecord->participant_zip_code,
                $eventRecord->participant_language,
                $eventRecord->participant_is_customer,
                $eventRecord->participant_current_carrier,
                $eventRecord->participant_is_contact,
                $eventRecord->participant_created_date,
                $eventRecord->creating_user_first_name,
                $eventRecord->creating_user_last_name,
                $eventRecord->creating_user_email,
                $eventRecord->participant_selected_date,
                $eventRecord->selecting_user_first_name,
                $eventRecord->selecting_user_last_name,
                $eventRecord->selecting_user_email
            ], null, 'A' . $sheetRowIndex);
            $sheetRowIndex++;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what happens when you make the chunk size smaller than `1000`?

Comment: I can try, but I don’t think that should make a huge difference based on my understanding of how Chunk works? There’s no way that a single chunk is anywhere close to 512 MB

Comment: well the spreadsheet is holding every row added to it but that seems like a lot of memory

Comment: True, but theoretically the spreadsheet should just be storing those data as strings, which are pretty memory-light

Comment: You could try PhpSpreadsheet's [Memory saving feature](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/memory_saving/)